# Qt5 CMake can't find C++ STD library if a definition is added in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5, definition

### Here is the problem I am struggling with.

I am using CMake to build my Qt5 GUI project. I am using a custom module [QML-material project](https://github.com/papyros/qml-material) from GitHub.
The problem is that as it is said in the project documentation - in order to setup the module for your project, you should add a definition:

> add_definitions("-DQPM_INIT\(E\)=E.addImportPath\(QStringLiteral\(\"qrc:/\"\)\)\;")

But if this definition is added in CMakeLists.txt the project can't find C++ STD library. If I comment it out the STD features can be used again.

### About the definition meaning.

This macro basically calls addImportPath("qec:/") to the argument it is called with. In my case it is in main():

```
// Working example
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
QPM_INIT(engine);
```

But if I just change it and call addImportPath straight forward and remove the definition it doesn't find the custom QML modules.

```
// Not working example
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral("qrc:/"));
```

### My questions:

- Why a definition in CMake can block the project linking with the STD lib?
- Why if I replace the macro with its representation in the main() function it doesn't work?
- Does anyone have a proposal how to use both the custom module and the STD library together?

NB! The Qt libraries are still visible. The problem is only with the STD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the compilers does not tolerate function like definitions. Adding such a macro with add_definition is a workaround as it adds the macro to CXX_FLAGS, not to CXX_DEFINES, but apparently it doesn't work properly too.